# I have the following XML and I'm trying to read the related_items section into a list but my code returns no result

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML and I'm trying to read the related_items section into a list but my code returns no result

```
<classification xmlns="http://server.com/specs_xml_2_0.xsd">
     <minor_class_code>CONVHD</minor_class_code>
     <minor_class_description>CONVERTIBLE HOOD</minor_class_description>
     <color_code>S</color_code>
     <color_code_description>Stainless Steel</color_code_description>
     <this_item_in_other_colors>
        <product>
           <key>BOSCH:DUH30122UC</key>
           <color_code>W</color_code>
           <color_code_description>White</color_code_description>
        </product>
        <product>
           <key>BOSCH:DUH30162UC</key>
           <color_code>B</color_code>
           <color_code_description>Black</color_code_description>
        </product>
     </this_item_in_other_colors>
     <width_string>30</width_string>
     <related_items>
        <related_item_key>BOSCH:DHZ3002UC</related_item_key>
        <related_item_key>BOSCH:D889872UC</related_item_key>
     </related_items>
```

The XML is an XmlNode. I'm loading it into an XDocument and I have this code

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader(node));
var query = xdoc.Descendants("related_item_key").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

But it returns empty list

Even with the code

```
var query = xdoc.Root.Element("related_items");
```

query gets value null.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code didn't consider default namespace which declared at the root element :

```
xmlns="http://server.com/specs_xml_2_0.xsd"
```

Notice that descendant elements without prefix inherit ancestor's default namespace *implicitly*. You can use *`XNamespace` + element's local name* to reference element in a non-empty namespace :

```
XNamespace d = "http://server.com/specs_xml_2_0.xsd";
var query = xdoc.Descendants(d+"related_item_key")
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this already, but I get the following error: Additional information: The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name. Any workaround?

Comment: Actually it worked. My initial (wrong) code was var d = "http://server.com/specs_xml_2_0.xsd"; instead of XNamespace d = "http://server.com/specs_xml_2_0.xsd";

Answer (score 0):

I put this VB together as a test.  It seems to work.

```
Imports <xmlns="http://server.com/specs_xml_2_0.xsd">
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim xe As XElement
        xe = <classification xmlns="http://server.com/specs_xml_2_0.xsd">
                 <minor_class_code>CONVHD</minor_class_code>
                 <minor_class_description>CONVERTIBLE HOOD</minor_class_description>
                 <color_code>S</color_code>
                 <color_code_description>Stainless Steel</color_code_description>
                 <this_item_in_other_colors>
                     <product>
                         <key>BOSCH:DUH30122UC</key>
                         <color_code>W</color_code>
                         <color_code_description>White</color_code_description>
                     </product>
                     <product>
                         <key>BOSCH:DUH30162UC</key>
                         <color_code>B</color_code>
                         <color_code_description>Black</color_code_description>
                     </product>
                 </this_item_in_other_colors>
                 <width_string>30</width_string>
                 <related_items>
                     <related_item_key>BOSCH:DHZ3002UC</related_item_key>
                     <related_item_key>BOSCH:D889872UC</related_item_key>
                 </related_items>
             </classification>

        Dim relatedItemsSection As IEnumerable(Of XElement)

        relatedItemsSection = xe...<related_items>

        Dim relatedItems As IEnumerable(Of XElement)

        relatedItems = relatedItemsSection...<related_item_key>

    End Sub
End Class
```